# How to make Range-based Bar Chart (Recharts)

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I want to make BarChart using `Recharts` like below.

[image]

But, I can't find a solution in an [official document](https://recharts.org/en-US/).

Do you know any idea?
Thanks to read this question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an unsupported feature with the current version of recharts. You can however achieve the desired effect by implementing the following workaround.

### Workaround

1. Create `<YAxis yAxisId={"someId"}>` for each of children that overlap on the graph. For example, in your case `"Sleep"`, which has 2 entries on the same row would necessitate 2 Y-Axes.
2. Set all axes except the first one to hidden.
3. For each instance that overlaps (i.e. if sleep has entries [0,3] and [22, 22.5]), create separate key (i.e. `sleep1`, `sleep2`).
4. Map the new axes to new keys.

### Minimal example

You will note that while this approach allows you to order data they way you want to (i.e. multiple bars per row), because of splitting them across different, hidden axes - the bar fill colour will not match. Setting the labels will be equally problematic.

##### Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Bar,
  ComposedChart,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
} from 'recharts';

function GanttChart() {
  const data = [
    // Top row (sleep)
    { a1: [0, 3], a2: [22, 23] },

    // Bottom row (work)
    { a1: [9, 20] }
  ];

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
      <ComposedChart
        data={data}
        layout="vertical"
      >
        <XAxis type="number" domain={[0, 24]} tickCount={13} />
        <YAxis yAxisId="y1" type="category" />
        <YAxis yAxisId="y2" type="category" hide />
        <Bar yAxisId="y1" dataKey="a1" fill="blue" />
        <Bar yAxisId="y2" dataKey="a2" fill="red" />
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}
```

##### Result:

[image]

### Full example

To reproduce the graph from your image, the following code can be used. It's primarily using the principles from above, with some additional JS gymnastics to pass the right attributes to right places and make the data format easier to work with.

##### Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Bar,
  ComposedChart,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
} from 'recharts';

function GanttChart() {
  const data = {
    sleep: {
      label: 'Sleep',
      fill: 'blue',
      data: [
        [0, 3],
        [22, 23],
      ],
    },
    work: {
      label: 'Work',
      fill: 'red',
      data: [[9, 20]],
    },
  };

  const yAxisPrefix = 'yAxis';

  // Get the largest number of entries in a single row to determine number of y-axes.
  const maxOverlap = Math.max(
    ...Object.keys(data).map((key) => data[key].data.length)
  );

  const yAxes = [];
  const bars = [];

  // Create y-axes and bars
  Array.from({ length: maxOverlap }, (_, i) => i).forEach((i) => {
    const id = `${yAxisPrefix}${i}`;
    yAxes.push(
      <YAxis
        key={`yaxis-${id}`}
        yAxisId={id}
        type="category"
        hide={i !== 0}
        dataKey="label"
      />
    );
    bars.push(<Bar key={`yaxis-${id}`} yAxisId={id} dataKey={id} />);
  });

  const graphMap = {};
  const graphData = [];

  // Prepare data in a format for recharts and pass additional attributes (fill, label)
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    const obj = {};
    graphMap[key] = [];
    data[key].data.forEach((entry, i) => {
      const newKey = `${yAxisPrefix}${i}`;
      obj[newKey] = entry;
      // Provide the label and fill which will be used by the Bar
      obj.fill = data[key].fill;       // Pass fill from data definition
      obj.label = data[key].label;     // Pass label from data definition
      graphMap[key].push(newKey);
    });
    graphData.push(obj);
  });

  // 

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
      <ComposedChart data={graphData} layout="vertical">
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis type="number" domain={[0, 24]} tickCount={13} />
        {yAxes}
        {bars}
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}
```

##### Data format explained:

This is what the `graphMap` and `graphData` look like before returning. By plotting the fill and label into the graph data objects we capitalise on rechats automatically grabbing it from the data, which saves us from having to define custom `shape` attribute for each of the bars and passing it in manually.

```json
{
  "graphMap": {
    "sleep": [ "yAxis0", "yAxis1" ],
    "work": [ "yAxis0" ],
  },
  "graphData": [
    {
      "yAxis0": [ 0, 3 ],
      "yAxis1": [ 22, 23 ]
      "fill": "blue",
      "label": "Sleep",
    },
    {
      "yAxis0": [ 9, 20 ],
      "fill": "red",
      "label": "Work"
    }
  ]
}
```

##### Result:

[image]